# For $\frac{a}{b}>\frac{c}{d}$ I can write $\frac{c}{d} = \frac{a}{d'}$ with $d'=b+\epsilon$, $\epsilon>0$

Tags: proof-verification, fractions

> Can I **always** write $\frac{c}{d} = \frac{a}{d'}$ with $d'=b+\epsilon$ when $\frac{a}{b}>\frac{c}{d}$?

Assume $a,b,c,d$ are integers and are $>0$ (since comments provided a counterexample when they can be negative)

(if something is wrong and it is not true than perhaps it is true for $a>b, c>d$, but first lets try the general case)

I realize this is trivial, but it seems to me like it shouldn't necessarily be true (specifically, this seems like I can get from any fraction to another just by changing one of the denominator/numerator?)

---

Proof attempt:
We want to find some $d'$ such that $\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a}{d'}$.

Solving for $d'$ we get $$d' = \frac{d}{c} \cdot a$$

Since $\frac{a}{b}>\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a}{d'}$, it must be that $d' > b$ which implies that $d' = b+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon = d'-b$.

This shows what we wanted to show.

(note: so if $d>c$ then $d'>a$, if $c>d$ then $d'<a$

Comment: Try $\frac{-1}{1}>\frac{-2}{1}$. Can you write $\frac{-1}{1+\epsilon}=-2$ with $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: @A.Γ. Ah, indeed that is a counterexample. But if we require strictly positive numerator/denominator? (or, instead if we allow $\epsilon$ to be negative I think we are okay). I think it just seems weird to me that if I have $\frac{a}{b}>\frac{c}{d}$ I can get $\frac{c}{d}$ from $\frac{a}{b}$ just by increasing the denominator (I feel like there should be some "in-between" fraction that I cannot get).

Comment: Let $c/d=C$. Study the graph of $y=\frac{a}{x}$. In particular, can you say that if $y>C$ then $y=C$ at some point to the right? That is, if a point on the graph is above the line $y=C$ then the line intersects the graph at some point to the right? Consider, two cases: $a>0$ and $a<0$.

Comment: @A.Γ. If $a>0$ then $y=C$ somewhere to the right. if $a<0$ then $y=C$ somewhere to the left. So if I let $\epsilon$ be $>0$ or $<0$ I can indeed get anything just by changing the denominator. Pretty cool! (Now I'm wondering if this has to do with denseness of the reals or something, but that's thoughts for another time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure,

If $0 < \frac cd < \frac ab$ then

$\frac cd = \frac cd*\frac aa = \frac a{a\frac dc}$

Since $\frac cd < \frac ab$ then $\frac cd > \frac ba$ so

$a\frac dc > a\frac ba = b$.

.... In general for an $M,N$ there is an $s $ so that $M = N*s$ and if $t=\frac 1t$ then $M = N \frac 1t$ and if $0 < M < N$ then $0< s < 1$ and $t > 1$.

So... this really shouldn't seem like it shouldn't be true.  It should seem that it must be true.

(Of course negatives "turn things around")

So just let $d' = a\frac dc> b$ and let $\epsilon = d' - b>0$.

That's all there is to it.